# Strange issue with calendar day view

Tags: fullcalendar

My fullCalendar is setup and working about 99%.

However I have a strange issue when navigating through the day view(agendaDay).

When going through the days in day view, I never see any events even if there are events on that day.

However, if I switch to Month or Week view(which does show all events correctly), then go back to day view, the events suddenly show up in day view.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have all day events. Set all events to allDay=false and/or allDayDefault to false. More [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).
The allday events are supposed to show up in a row above 00:00 but if you don't have that row you can't see them at all. Setting allDay to false solved it for me anyways.